# Jquery Datepicker trigger after changing month (after month renders)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I want to highlight some days in the current month. I can do this on the first month, but not on a new month after "next month" or "prev month" is clicked. I tried using onChangeMonthYear event but this executes before the new (or prev) month renders.

any ideas?

Comment: This is my one, single biggest gripe with jQuery plugin developers - I have yet to see one where they trigger custom events so people like you and I can get some custom functionality.

Comment: @Peter Every custom event used in jQuery UI is documented in detail on the jQuery UI site.

Comment: @Alex, you miss my point.  Plugins should fire their own events so that the parent scripts can catch those and take action.  Something like `$(this).trigger( 'ui-datepicker:after-month-loaded' )` would let user278860 do what he's asking for - he'd just need to add a `$.bind()`

Comment: @Alex - *No*. Those **are not** custom triggered events.  Those are event callbacks. I'm not going to go into the differences involved, and power afforded by custom triggered events here in the comments.  Let's just say that I'm aware of what jQuery UI components do, and what I *wish* they did.

Comment: hmmm are we talking about 2 different datepickers here? the one I've always used is from jquery.com and you call it (all letters lowercase) "$.datepicker();" but the link vitch gave us is "$.datePicker();".. with a couple of undocumented functions (on jquery.com) like "renderCallback".

Comment: Yeah - I am talking about a different date picker, not the jQuery UI one... The link to mine is in my answer. The last time I looked at the UI one (a long time ago) it didn't have the beforeShowDay callback so I didn't know if the request was possible with that date picker... Since it seems like it is, I guess the original poster should stick with the UI picker and that solution. (side note - I would have called my picker something different to avoid confusion but it predates the jQuery UI one by quite some time)

Comment: I used `setTimeout` function with 200ms delay inside `onChangeMonthYear` callback function. This way, the calendar has a chance of getting rendered.

Comment: After searching SO, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337622/1057527), which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best choice is going to be the `beforeShowDay` callback.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay

You can specify a new class name for the cell, based on whatever your date criteria is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with my [jQuery datepicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) using a custom "renderCallback".

e.g. [This example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerCustomCellRender.html) disables weekends and adds a class for styling those days. There are lots of other more [complex examples](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerLimitAvailableDatesAjax2.html) which might help too...

```
$('.date-pick')
    .datePicker(
        {
            renderCallback:function($td, thisDate, month, year)
            {
                if (thisDate.isWeekend()) {
                    $td.addClass('weekend');
                    $td.addClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Also, if you would prefer, there is a [dpMonthChanged](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html) event once the calendar has re-rendered and you can loop over the contents of the calendar and do your highlighting...

Answer (score 0):

```
        hack:
         $('#calendar').datepicker({
                                    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                                        setEventsDay()
                                    }
                                 });
function setEventsDay(){
    var days = $(".ui-state-default");
                   console.log(days.length);   //31 from august to Sep 
        setTimeout(function () {
                    var days = $(".ui-state-default");
                   console.log(days.length);     //30 `enter code here`from august to Sep 

                }, 100)
    }
```