# Fire function after jQuery UI datepicker has rendered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to add a hover to all .ui-state-default elements (cells) of a datepicker. The hover uses class information added by the beforeShowDay function. I need a way to be able to rebind the hover whenever the calendar is re-rendered by changing months/year.

I've tried beforeShow, but it is only called on the first time the datepicker is displayed.

I've tried the onChangeMonthYear, but it is called prior to beforeShowDay, so any hovers I add are on the previous months .ui-state-default elements. Is there a way to bind to the datepicker after the beforeShowDay has been called? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some script?

Comment: I have a similar issue before that i resolved with the setTimeout function. eg: `setTimeout(someFunction,1);`. Dirty, but works.

Comment: Why not use on() with delegated events? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pfdj8/3/

Comment: What's the hover effect you're demonstrating?

Comment: Simply to grab the class that is added to the cell. I'm really attaching an ID that corresponds to an event on that day. So I plan on grabbing the ID and then searching for other cells with the same class so that I can highlight all cells with the ID.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Maybe post some code or pseudo-code to better illustrate.

Comment: Yeah, I posted this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pfdj8/3/. Open the console and notice that the hover fires, but once you switch months it doesn't bind.

Comment: @Phillip Whisenhunt: That's because the calendar gets rendered again with the new months, days, etc and you loose your bindings. I found a workaround this problem: inside `onChangeMonthYear` callback, I use `setTimeout('myFunction', 200);`. This way, the calendar is rendered before `myFunction` callback is called. I hope the 'jQuery Datepicker' team adds some late callbacks in the near future, after the calendar is rendered.

Comment: After searching SO, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6337622/1057527), which solves the problem.