# jQuery Datepicker, event AFTER select, not "onSelect"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

So I'm coding a calendar from the jQuery UI datepicker and this renewing of instance thing is driving me insane.

The goal is to fill the calendar with events from a normal table, with the correct information (Date is given within the table) it works fine. It populates the calendar with events and you can drag and drop them to update the table with correct information. All this is done.

HOWEVER; I want too be able to click on a date, and create a event for the specific date selected, this is easy. However when I click all the previous events get removed because the instance of the Calendar is refreshed. (It's really hard to explain).

The function "initialize" is what gives every TD in the calendar a UL (for dragndrop) with correct "date" attr, and populates the UL with LI's from an external table.

So if I do:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    firstDay: 1, //Mon-Sun
    onSelect: function() { initialize(); }
});
```

Nothing happens.. But if i do it:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    firstDay: 1, //Mon-Sun
    onSelect: function() { initialize();alert(); }
});
```

You can actually see the calendar being populated correctly, (the alert prevents code from going further), but when pressing "OK" the calendar instance is refreshed and events are gone.

So what I'd need is an kind of "afterNewInstanceCreated:" command to work from..
Any ideas?

Here is how it looks atm: (JSFiddle), click on a date too see the "magic".
http://jsfiddle.net/N97QA/

Would really appriciate any help

Comment: It sounds like `onSelect` is the event you want, however something in the `initialize()` function is clearing the data. Check the code there.

Comment: Not a solution, but adding an `e.preventDefault()` seems to be a step in the right direction, I think? http://jsfiddle.net/N97QA/1/

Comment: No it is not, the onSelect fires before it is selected. (Before the class "ui-state-active" is applied, I want to run my code after this.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan If it was the initialize function then it wudn't display anything since its completed when the alert hits, so its NOT this.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334898/jquery-datepicker-after-update-event-or-equivalent):

if you need a "afterShow"-event before jquery-ui version 1.9 you can overwrite the datepicker._updateDatepicker function.

for example:

```
$(function() {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
        var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
        if (afterShow)
            afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));  // trigger custom callback
    }
});
```

Now the datepicker raise an "afterShow" event after every update from the datepicker element.
Then just use this event in datapicker

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    afterShow: function() {console.log("it works")}
});
```