# initialize select2 dropdown on jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I have an application with all the drop down boxes customized by select2 plugin, obviously like this:

```
$("select").select2();
```

However, the select element on a jquery datepicker is not customized. And I couldn't figure out where to initialize this in the jquery datepicker function. The following is what I want to achive. I want a function that can replace init that can get the datepicker dom element.

```
$(".datepickerInput").datepicker({
  init : function(datepickerElement) {
     datepickerElement.find("select").select2();
  }
});
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that [`Datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) doesn't have a "after show" callback function. That is, there is no available method/option that can run code after the datepicker has been showned.

There is some discussion and some possible answers in  [jQuery Datepicker "After Update" Event or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334898/jquery-datepicker-after-update-event-or-equivalent)

So, for now, you can make that work by extending Datepicker, like this:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Code from the related question. Used the answer from @Markus
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
    var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
    if (afterShow)
        afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));  // trigger custom callback
    }

    // Now that we have `afterShow`, we can initialize Select2.
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        afterShow: function() {
            $(".ui-datepicker select").select2();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is now working :) That afterShow function should really be considered in datepicker.