# Implementing url on jquery datepicker's date button

Tags: jquery, url, datepicker

Recently I have integrated Jquery's datepicker into my website and it worked fine.

Now I have came to a problem that I can't figure out a solution.

I want to make the date buttons on the datepicker become `<a></a>` tag. That mean for example when the cursor hover on the "2014-09-09" date, the url appear in the status bar (left bottom) of the browser is : mysite.com/look-for-date?date="2014-09-09"

Can i achieve that using Jquery Datepicker? If possible, I'm eager to learn how! Thanks!

Comment: Can't be done simply I'm afraid. Jquery's datepicker doesn't dispatch an appropriate event. If is had one, then it would  be called something like `onDateHover`. Maybe some other datepicker is so equipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k2faz58e/1/

**HTML:**

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

**JQ:**

```
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
        var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
        if (afterShow)
            afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));  // trigger custom callback
    }

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        afterShow :function(){
         var $dp=$("#ui-datepicker-div");

          $dp.find('.ui-state-default').each(function(){
                var $td=$(this).parents('td');
                var month=parseInt($td.attr('data-month'));                
                month++;
                var year=$td.attr('data-year')
                var day=parseInt($(this).text());
                if(month<10) month='0'+month;
                if(day<10) day='0'+day;
                var date=year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
              $(this).attr('href','mysite.com/look-for-date?date='+date);
          });

        },
    });
```

**SOLUTION 2 - div targtet**

**new:** http://jsfiddle.net/4p0trbz2/

**HTML:**

```
<p>Date: <div id="datepicker"></div></p>
```

**JQ:**

```
$(function() {

    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334898/jquery-datepicker-after-update-event-or-equivalent
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
        $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
        var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
        if (afterShow)
        {
            afterShow.apply( $( "#datepicker" )[0]);  // trigger custom callback
        }
    }

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        afterShow :function(){
         var $dp=$(".ui-datepicker-inline");
         $dp.css( "display", "block" );

          $dp.find('.ui-state-default').each(function(){
                var $td=$(this).parents('td');
                var month=parseInt($td.attr('data-month'));                
                month++;
                var year=$td.attr('data-year')
                var day=parseInt($(this).text());
                if(month<10) month='0'+month;
                if(day<10) day='0'+day;
                var date=year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
                $(this).attr('href','mysite.com/look-for-date?date='+date);
          }).click(function(){
                window.location=$(this).attr('href');
          });          

        },
    });
});
```

Comment: solution for afterShow event taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334898/jquery-datepicker-after-update-event-or-equivalent

Comment: check solution 2 with div instead of input tag

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot! I'll award the bonus when it reachs the eligible time!

Comment: Hi! There is another problem! The link doesn't work, I mean I can open new link by clicking it! I have to write a small script for `onSelect` function, this loses the entire purpose of implementing the `<a>` tag :(

Comment: I have problem with jsfiddle and code update.  Shows the old code and will not update the correct code. Copy JQ sourece directly from answer above (SOLUTION 2). Pay attention to clikc function on end.