# JQuery UI datepicker - How to use event handler for _generateHTML event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to use JQuery .on() to listen for the _generateHTML event?
Am thinking the event name in my example is wrong.
Any ideas?

```
$jq(".ui-datepicker").datepicker().on("datepicker._generateHTML", function(){
    $jq(".ui-datepicker").prepend(headerHtml);
    console.log("It works!");
});
```

This is the specific event I want to monitor:

```
    /* Generate the HTML for the current state of the date picker. */
    _generateHTML: function( inst ) {
```

Found in JQuery UI:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Or do just I need to monkey-patch it? Would rather not

Comment: `_generateHTML` is a Function not an event. It is executed by `_updateDatepicker()`. All sorts of stuff executes this function. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @Twisty thanks for the pointer, that helped lots.

Solved it :)
`$jq.datepicker._updateDatepickerOriginal = $jq.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
 $jq.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
  $jq.datepicker._updateDatepickerOriginal(inst);
  $jq(".ui-datepicker").prepend(headerHtml);
  console.log("It works!");

 };`

My intension was to add HMTL to datepicker div after every update/refresh.
This post was very helpful in finding the right syntax etc:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334898/jquery-datepicker-after-update-event-or-equivalent)