# jquery ui calendar resets elements properties on change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, qtip2

I have a setup where I use a Jquery UI calendar and Qtip for displaying a text associated to each day of the month.

I initate the UI component like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({                
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2
    });
```

And after this I initiate the qtips:

```
$('#datepicker').find("td").each(function(){
        $(this).qtip({    
          content:  {   text: tips[$(this).attr('title')]  },
          show: {   solo: true  },    
          hide: 'unfocus'
        });
    })
```

I keep the information that needs to be displayed in this array called 'tips' that I populate from the database. The issue is that whenever I change the month or click on a date the qtip will not display anymore.

I tried this workaround but it is not working:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({                
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
             $('#datepicker').find("td").each(function(){
                $(this).qtip({    
                  content:  {   text: tips[$(this).attr('title')]  },
                  show: {   solo: true  },    
                  hide: 'unfocus'
                });
            })
        }
    });
```

Any ideas on how can I preserve the qtips even whan the user clicks on day elements and changes the month?

**Update #1**

Here is a fiddle that replicates the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ZKtAZ/3/ (updated fiddle)

**Update #2**

Tried "on" as EmirCalabuch suggested but still on month change it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/ZKtAZ/9/.

I might be saying something stupid but when the calendar changes the month it is actually resetting the whole datepicker and this might be the reason why it is not working.

**Update #3**

I found a solution to this that you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/ZKtAZ/11/.

Actually I had to bind a click event to the datepicker so that it will set proper actions on the month change.

The issue with the day clicked was solved using this piece of code when initating the picker:

```
onSelect: function (date, inst) {
        inst.inline = false;
    }
```

The solution was found using this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2312825/1168944

Thank youu all for your time and contribution.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Yes sir. I will work on it right now

Comment: Your fiddle is not showing your problem, there is some other error.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'replace' ` at jquery-ui.min.js:9

Comment: I updated the fiddle. There was something missing there.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI datepicker has (at least the latest versions) internal tooltip support, so you do not need to add qtip. To apply a tooltip text to a specific date, on the `beforeShowDay` function, just return a three element array (you currently return two). The third element is the tooltip text you want to display when that date is hovered, if there is one.

I've posted a fiddle here that shows how this would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/CFMru/

Regarding your problem, the `onChangeMonthYear()` method is called before the datepicker's table is actually created so you cannot setup qtip on that. If you still want to use qtip for your tooltips, your best bet I think would be to intercept the hover event using `live()` or `on()`, check if you need to display a tooltip on the current date and then show the tooltip statically. Using `on()` or `live()` guarantees your code will be called even on DOM elements that do not exist yet:

```
$('#datepicker tbody td').on('mouseenter', function() {
    // Reconstruct the hovered date
    var closest_datepicker = $(this).closest('div.ui-datepicker-group');
    var month = closest_datepicker.find('span.ui-datepicker-month').text();
    var year = closest_datepicker.find('span.ui-datepicker-year').text();
    var day = $(this).text();

    // Look for the date in the array

    // Show the tooltip
    $(this).qtip({show: {ready: true}, hide: {fixed : true}, content: 'Your content' });
}

// Attach a mouseleave event as well to hide the tooltip
$('#datepicker tbody td').on('mouseleave', function() {
    // Destroy the tooltip, it will be recreated when hovered again
    $(this).qtip("destroy");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, only I need to display html code in the tip window, which the default tooltip will not display. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/CFMru/1/. I have tried your version too but still when changing the month the qtip does not preserve itself http://jsfiddle.net/ZKtAZ/5/